# analyzing a 2D array by columns

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have the following 2D array and I want to compare all the columns with each other.

```
    int [][] myarray={{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

So what I want to see is if column 1 (all 1's) is equal to the values in column 2 (all 2's).

Ps. the array size is not just limited to this.

Comment: Are you wishing to return a simple true/false?  True if they're all equal and false if there are any differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question whether you want to compare all columns to each other, or just a single column to another single column (for example column 1 to column 2).  Assuming you meant the latter, you could do this.

```
public boolean columnsIdentical(int[][] array, int colIndex1, int colIndex2) {
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++ ) {
        if (array[row][colIndex1] != array[row][colIndex2]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<myarray[0].length;i++) {
   int comp=myarray[0][i];
   for (int j=1;j<myarray.length;j++) {
      if (myarray[j][i] != comp) {
            // no match
      } else {
            // match
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test all pairs of columns you need 3 loops

1. Innermost compares elements of columns A and B
2. Middle loops through B, skipping columns already checked
3. Outermost loops through A for all columns